# Ajax POST on page refresh?

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery, post

I have written a quick bit of Ajax, to post the values of a form when i click the submit button. That part works fine!

the problem i have, is that after i've clicked submit, the form stays populated and doesn't clear. Am i missing an extra line of code here? Any ideas?

here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $("#subscribe-form").submit(function(s)
    {
        var postData1 = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL1 = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax(
        {
            url : formURL1,
            type: "POST",
            data : postData1,
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
            {
                alert('test alert');
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
            //if fails      
            }
        });
    s.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    });

    $("#subscribe-form").submit(); //Submit  the FORM
</script>
```

Comment: Hi guys, anyone have an answer for this? i'm sure it's fairly easy, and definitely possible, but i can't seem to find the right syntax for this anywhere. Thanks, Gavin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the answer to this.

Within the `success()` callback, I added the following piece of code:

```
$("#subscribe-form")[0].reset();
```